# How to install python 3.9 (32bit) to Linux server (without GUI) via wine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, wine

I'm struggle with the problem: I have a Python app that works fine in Windows, but this script need to be running in Linux Ubuntu server. Script bases on the library that works only in 32bit version of Python and uses some Windows dll files, so author of the library recommends to install python and this library on *nix systems via wine.

So i download 32bit python installer and... realise that i can't install Python without GUI, because exe file needs display. Even "wineconsole python-3.10.10.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0" gives error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-109:~$ wineconsole python-3.10.10.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0
0050:err:explorer:initialize_display_settings Failed to query current display settings for L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1".
00f4:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
00f4:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
```

Is there any possible solutions to solve this problem?

I tried /quiet, /passive commands but it is still the same error

I tried to use xvfb, but unsuccessful:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0.0 wine python-3.10.10.exe
0024:err:ole:com_get_class_object class {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} not registered
0024:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} could be created for context 0x1
```

Comment: How are you trying to install Python then? Because on a Ubuntu server normally Python is present by default. isn't it possible to use that version from Wine?

Comment: @Pianoman yes, you are right, Python was on Ubuntu server by default, 64 bit version. 
But I need 32 bit version with some Windows dependencies so it is necessary to install Python via Wine...

Comment: Maybe a portable version of Python can be used; these are installations that are more unpacked than installed. Otherwise, maybe this helps: https://github.com/bitranox/install_python_on_wine_and_travis

Comment: thank you, @Pianoman , i'll try it